# How to detect if the browser's representation of "new line" has two characters?

Tags: javascript, browser, opera

I understand that Opera considers `\n\r` a new line inside textareas. And some IE versios.
If I press Enter inside a textarea, I'll get new lines with `\n\r`

In other browsers the new line is just `\n`.

How can I detect this in my script?

I could use `window.opera` to find out if the browser is Opera, but people say I should try to detect browser features instead of the actual browser.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: bc I'm trying to use `setSelectionRange(a,b)` to select a part of the textarea, and I need to correctly determine `a`

Comment: What part are you trying to select? Is there anything special about `a` or `b`, or about the text being selected and its location? There might be another way depending on the pattern you're trying to match.

Comment: Just check the `value` property of the textarea (e.g. `input.value.indexOf("\r\n") > -1`) when you need to. My answer to your related question has an example of this. Perhaps you hadn't seen that I'd updated that answer?

Comment: Think of it like a toolbar button from the stackoverflow editor. For example, when you press the "code" button without selecting any text, you get a string added in the text area ` insert your code here`. And I want to select that text

Comment: Btw, I've written a jQuery plug-in that deals with that kind of thing: http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my other answer, but it occurred to me that the creation of a dedicated textarea is not required, you can determine this with the subject textarea, so long as it has any newlines in it.  if it doesn't, not knowing won't affect your range.

```
<textarea id="yourEditor">foo
bar
bing
baz</textarea>
```

and then test it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newlineSize() {
    var val = document.getElementById('yourEditor').value;
    var len = 0;
    if (1 < val.split("\r").length) {
        len++;
    }
    if (1 < val.split("\n").length) {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="alert(newlineSize());" value="test">
```

This will return/alert the width of a newline in your textarea.

Comment: This is the right kind of way to go. I mentioned this kind of approach in a comment under the question.

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work (i.e. returns the desired `true`) in the latest Opera and IE 7+. However, this is untested in older versions and I suspect is unnecessary. See my comments on the question.

**Update**: Improved thanks to a comment from @Umbrella below.

```
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.value = "\n";
var twoCharLineBreaks = (textarea.value == "\r\n");
alert(twoCharLineBreaks);
```

Comment: I like this, because it's much cleaner than my idea, but it is returning a false negative when I test it in IE.

Comment: Replacing the second line with `textarea.value="\n";` seems to give expected results.

Comment: @Umbrella: Your version using `value` is better; I had suspected it wouldn't work but it does seem to, so I'll change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how one **should check** for that.  I hope someone does, but in case no one does, I have an idea about how **you can test** for that.  Add (hard code) a textarea with a known value containing a newline, then check its length.

```
<textarea style="visibility:hidden" id="newlineTest">foo
bar</textarea>
```

Make sure the second line (containing 'bar') has no indentation/leading whitespace/tabs, and then test it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newlineSize() {
    var len = document.getElementById('newlineTest').value.length;
    alert(len);
    if (8 == len) {
        return 2;
    } else if (7 ==len) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return null; //unknown condition
    }
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="alert(newlineSize());" value="test">
```

Naturally you'd want to ditch the alerts and save it in a var.  Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari (all mac), returned 1. IE8(XP) returned 2.

Comment: This will probably fail because the textarea contains the newline character your editor uses.

Comment: @timing: Doesn't follow. This has a chance.